# How to split a list by its element in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a List / Seq looks like:

```
case class elmt(id:Int, value:Int)

val myinput = Seq(elmt(1,10), elmt(2,11), elmt(3,12))
```

I want to split the list to get:

```
l1 = (1,2,3)
l2 = (10,11,12)
```

How can I implement the split function? thanks,

Comment: I figured it out by myself myinput.unzip(x=>(x.id,x.value))

Comment: ... and as can be seen on the example of `Seq`, class names and types are usually written beginning with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself

```
myinput.unzip(x=>(x.id,x.value))
```